# TeXstudio doesn't save changes to preferences

Tags: texstudio

Any changes applied to the TeXstudio preferences vanish after the program was closed. Saving and loading them via a user profile is possible, though imho quite complicated. Does anybody know that problem or can guess its cause? Maybe TeXstudio has not enough rights to save the changes. I'll be thankful for any hints.

Comment: Changes are saved to `texstudio.ini`. Its [location depends on your OS (Link)](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions). Check the rights and if the file is actually modified when closing TXS.

Comment: @ Tim, google takes one here, would you like to add this as an answer?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: I find a solution. It seems that the preference file is located at ~/.config/texstudio folder, and on my computer that folder is ready only to me. So I changed the permission to read and write and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to TeXstudio FAQ ([Where are the settings stored?](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions#Where_are_the_settings_stored.3F)) for the installer versions the configuration file is stored in local user directories, where by definition a user has writing rights. When this does not work, you have a serious problem, but this does not come within the scope of TeX.SE. The portable version can be extracted almost everywhere on a system. If this was done by you, you needed writing rights back in time, but if it was done by another one, let’s say an administrator, and you weren’t granted writing rights for this directory, then this is some kind of misconfiguration, and this is also not on-topic on TeX.SE.